# Правильный выбор коллекции

Tags: java

Подскажите лучшую коллекцию в плане производительности в ситуации, когда нужно очень часто её создавать и пополнять. При этом порядок добавления элементов должен сохраняться, а самих элементов в коллекции немного, максимум штук 30.

Comment: Думаю для ваших целей, подойдет `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @And не гарантирует сохранения порядка, и автор ничего не писал про многопоточность.

Comment: Что значит часто создавать? Вы не можете часто создавать одну коллекцию. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Выберите любую. Например LinkedList. При 30 элементах нет абсолютно никакой разницы в плане производительности

Comment: Часто создавать в смысле будет объект создаваться новый данной коллекции очень часто. В коллекцию будут добавляться отдельные элементы, если точнее, то отдельные строки.

Comment: Как на счет взять интерфейс List и свою имплементацию именно такую, какая вам будет нужна

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, он то не писал, но производительность и сортировка,сохранения позиций, разные вещи.

Comment: @And ага, в однопоточном коде `ConcurrentHashMap` медленнее. А сортировать коллекции не гарантирующие упорядоченности хоть и можно в некоторых реализациях, но всё же - плохая практика.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev. Хосподя, да параллельное программирование в разы быстрее. А темболее с использованием `ConcurrenHashMap`. Не забудьте полистать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выбирайте:
[image: Как выбрать коллекцию?]

Только [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) и [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) уже не используются, вместо них(для замены коллекции с синхронизацией) - [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

P.S. Похоже, вам нужен [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: наглядно. Интересно, есть подобное под C#?

Comment: @AK есть только сайт с чем то похожим, может кто-нибудь и пикчу сделает.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/collections/selecting-a-collection-class

Answer (score 3):

Тебе нужен список. При 30 элементах бери ArrayList. Даже при вставке в начало сдвиг 29 элементов вполне сравним по скорости (хотя, может быть и медленнее, не проверял) с выделением памяти и перестановкой 6 ссылок, к тому же ты получишь данные в кэше процессора, что обеспечит к ним быстрый доступ в последующем.

Comment: Плюсую. Максимальное испоьзование кеша рулит.

Comment: Я ранее нашёл рекомендацию использовать ArrayDeque, а что вы об этом думаете?

Answer (score 0):

Если основная операция- это добавление, то используй список т.к. вставка элемента за О(1) происходит.

Comment: Какой именно список? Ведь они разные по скорости, по сохранению порядка добавления, и т.п., у них много отличий.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList если вставка элементов в начало, LinkedList если в середину. Хотя, для 30 элементов, как писали выше, можете любой из этих вариантов использовать

Comment: С какого перепуга Linked в этом вопросе?

Comment: Уже исправил, наоборот :)

Comment: Да, наоборот лучше :)